# Why do both Convert.ToInt32(Byte) and Convert.ToInt32(Byte[]) compile, but Convert.ToInt32(byte[]) throw a runtime exception?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, visual-studio-2013, arrays

I get an invalidcastexception whenever I use `Convert.ToInt32(byte[])` and was wondering if I was doing something wrong, of if this is something that is well known.

Why is it that a byte[] doesn't throw a compiler error when there is no overload that supports a byte[] in this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't convert a `byte[]` to an int using `Convert.ToInt32`. 
You need to [use a `BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066.aspx).

The difference is that the BitConverter is built to do exactly what you're trying to do: take an array of bytes and convert them into their integral representation. `Convert.Int32` is meant for converting anything that's already an integer, or can be converted to an integer using the `IConvertible` interface.

`Convert` can be used only for types that implement the `IConvertible` interface.

Answer (score 4):

Because there is an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes `object` as parameter and a `byte[]` is an `object`.That's why you don't get a compile-time error.And `Byte[]` is not convertible to `Int32` and that's the reason of runtime-exception.

> **InvalidCastException**: value does not implement the IConvertible interface.
>   -or-
>   The conversion is not supported.

Instead you need to use [`BitConverter.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to convert byte array to `Int32`.

Comment: And byte array doesnt implements System.IConvertible

Comment: +1 for the description of my error.  I'll be accepting Mihai's answer, because he corrects my ignorance in handling this scenario